# ios - how to set UITableView number of rows and values in them so that they are recognized by id on click?

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a loop which parses JSON that is returned from a remote server, and I am able to loop through it, and get the values, but I am not sure how to set my UITableView with the data that comes back.

How do I reset the expected number of rows that the UITableView already thinks it will have? And how do I actually set the values?

Thanks!

Comment: @Stunner omg sorry, UITableView ...no wonder I couldn't find stuff while googling :) just changed my question to say UITableView

Comment: By the way, you mention that you have a loop to parse your JSON? Please have a look at NSJSONSerialization, it returns an array or dictionary straight from JSON with one line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the data in an array. Then reload the table once you have finished parsing the data, like so:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // when the array is empty, this will just return 0 and your table will 
    // be empty until your data is done downloading
    return [myArray count];
}
```

And in a method that parses your data:

```
-(void)parseFinished {
    // once the data finished downloading and parsing:
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

To know which object you need to pass into a view controller or do whatever else you need to do with the data:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SomeViewController *viewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] initObject:[myArray objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thank you - that helped! By any chance could you also explain to me how to handle the clicks...I mean how can I attach some id to pass along so that the system knows which item was chosen?

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question, you want...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *) didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
{
    NSUInteger column = path.column;
    NSUInteger row = path.row;

    //The row and/or column values should be useful in accessing your data source array.
}
```